# How to debug an AngularJS app using sublime text and Live Reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, sublimetext3

I'm developing an AngularJS app, and would like to use Sublime Text in combination with Live Reload to do my debugging. I was using WebStorm before, where I could just select my index.html, and right-click -> debug.
How do I achieve the same functionality using ST with Live Reload?
First - what tool or process do I use on my Mac, to serve my index.html to my Chrome browser?

The goal is to be able to edit a given html or JS file in ST, and have Chrom auto reload when the edited file is saved.

Comment: P.S. - I also have the Web Inspector package installed, so, if anyone knows how to debug using that, I would appreciate it

Comment: There is a tool called  xdebug for sublime text  but  think is to debug php I'm looking the same for angularjs

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm debugs both PHP and JS at the same time, if i'm not mistaken.
But since AngularJS is javascript, you could just use the google chrome developer tools or Firefox's firebug.